# Google analytics IOS tracking campaigns error No visible @interface for 'GAIDictionaryBuilder' declares the selector 'set:value:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, campaign-monitor

I am following the instructions contained here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder

Xcode refuses to compile since this statement

```
[hitParams set:kGAICampaignMedium value:@"referrer"];
```

gives this error:

```
No visible @interface for 'GAIDictionaryBuilder' declares the selector 'set:value:'
```

The same happens to the kGAICampaignSource

I have seen that the "correct" calls may be these two

```
[hitParams setValue:kGAICampaignMedium forKey:@"referrer"];
[hitParams setValue:kGAICampaignSource forKey:[url host]];
```

However there is another issue with the call:

```
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] setAll:hitParams] build]];
```

Which sends a warning because hitParams should be a NSDictionary and it is a GAIDictionaryBuilder.

Am I doing something wrong?
I have upgraded google analytics to the latest (3.10) version.

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific lines you are having trouble with aren't supported by that version of the SDK. It looks like the v3 SDK documentation is out of date (As at: 2 Dec 2014).

```
// hitparams is of type GAIDictionaryBuilder
[hitParams set:@"referrer" forKey:kGAICampaignMedium];
[hitParams set:[url host] forKey:kGAICampaignSource];

NSDictionary *paramDictionary = [hitParams build];
// -setAll: requires an NSDictionary
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] setAll:paramDictionary] build]];
```